# multiple String location find using a key in a tag

Tags: java, position, substring, match, stringbuilder

I want to parse an input eg: GH123FG12B1A58  .

'GH' / 'FG' / 'A' / 'B'   will be there in all the tags in same order but different position . eg: GH14555523FG1555552B55551A55558

Need to find the value after every keys

I see this can be done by using patter , get start & end index ?  Is there any other way to acomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Shipparse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner Iname = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the invoice :");
            String Maintag = Iname.nextLine();

            String GH = "GH";
            String FG = "FG";
            String AB = "AB";
            String B = "B";
            String A = "A";

            int cus = Maintag.indexOf(GH);  
            int cys = Maintag.indexOf(FG);
            int ats = Maintag.indexOf(AB);
            int ss = Maintag.indexOf(B);
            int se = Maintag.indexOf(A);

            int tlength = Maintag.length();

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(Maintag);

            String cnum;

            if ( ats == -1) {

                 cnum = str.substring((cus +2) , cys);
                 System.out.println("Customer :" + cnum);

                 String cyn = str.substring((cys + 2), ss);
                 System.out.println("Agent :" + cyn);

             } else {

                 cnum = str.substring((cus +2) , ats);
                 System.out.println("Customer  :" + cnum);

                 String cyn = str.substring((ats + 2), ss);
                 System.out.println("Company:" + cyn);
             }

             String spoint = str.substring((ss +1) , se);

             System.out.println("TYPE NUM:" + spoint);

             String send = str.substring((se +1) , tlength);
             System.out.println("FIELD NUM :" + send);

    }
}
```